# How to drag one section from form to another monitor in Asp.Net/Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with two sections, it would be like one section contains a web form for entering the fields.

second section contains the scanned image.
 
and users will have two monitors, they will drag the image section into other monitor, they will see the content from the second monitor and they have to type content in first monitor fields section.Requirement is very similar to call center application.

Process:
1.Monitor 1 contains a form which contains couple of fields to enter.

2.Monotor 1 contains a button called Open image.

3.When we click on image button, another web form has to open and it will contain the scanned image.

4. At the time of button click it self the newly opened scanned image has to move to the second monitor and it ha s to fit the screen.
5. so that users can see the second monitor scanned image , and they will type the data into the first monitor.

could any body provide information/the way how can we achive this functionality in Asp.Net mvc/Asp.Net.
Your response is highly valuable.

Comment: Are they two separate applications or is the browser stretched across the two windows?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: no one is asp.net MVC web form, on that form there will be a button, if we click on that button it has to open other webform with scanned images and it should move to another monitor and has to fit with second monitor.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot push the second webform to second monitor through ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop is provided by the OS and Browser and doesn't involve ASP.Net directly. You can read about drag and drop support in HTML 5

http://html5demos.com/drag-anything

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Once you've implemented the necessary attributes and events in HTML 5, you can upload to your ASP.Net server using XMLHttpRequest.